# Merge sort function

Tags: c, merge, sorting

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that recursively calls the merge sort function using the same parameters as the qsort function that is defined in the C library. However, although my values print out, they are not in order. Can somebody take a look at my function and tell me how to correct this? I'm also including the compare function that i used. thanks in advance

```
  int cmp (const void *first, const void *second)
    {  
        if (first < second)
            return -1;
        else if (first > second)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }



    static void msort (void *b,size_t n,size_t s, int(*cmp)(const void*,const void*) )

    {
        char *tmp;

        void *t;
        if ((t = malloc(s*n)) == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nError: No Memory.");
            return;
        }   
        char *b1, *b2;
        size_t n1, n2;



        n1 = n / 2;
        n2 = n - n1;
        b1 = b;
        b2 = (char *) b + (n1 * s);

        if (n2 <= n1)
            return;

        msort (b1, n2, s, cmp);
        msort (b2, n1+1, s, cmp);

        tmp = t;

        while (n1 > 0 && n2 > 0)
        {
            if ((*cmp) (b1, b2) <= 0)
            {
                memcpy (tmp, b1, s);
                tmp += s;
                b1 += s;
                --n1;
            }
            else
            {
                memcpy (tmp, b2, s);
                tmp += s;
                b2 += s;
                --n2;
            }
        }
        if (n1 > 0)
            memcpy (tmp, b1, n1 * s);
        memcpy (b, t, (n - n2) * s);
    }
```

here's my main. i left out some functions that you see here.

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    int *a, *b, *c;

printf("enter n: ");
if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 10)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "bad input.  goodbye\n");
    abort();
}

printf("sizeof(double) %d\n", sizeof(double) );

printf("running experiments with n=%d\n", n);

a = gen_int_array(n, 5000);
//b = clone_int_array(a, n);
c = clone_int_array(a, n);


//ssort(a, n);
//isort(b, n);
//msort_int(c, n);

//msort_int(d, n);
msort (c, n, sizeof(int), cmp );



if(n<50)
dump_int_array(c, n);

free(a);
free(b );
free(c);
```

}

Comment: "Look at my code and correct it" - the definition of "too localized," voting to close.

Comment: Do you have a *specific* question?

Comment: I'm trying to get suggestions on how to correct my merge sort function and make the values print out in order. you guys are acting like I'm asking you to write the whole code for me. I'm not. I did this myself, but I've been struggling to get my values in ascending order since this past friday. I'm at a blank

Answer (score 1):

One problem is your compare function; it is comparing the two pointers, that's all — not the values that are pointed at.  Since you don't show us the definition of the array that you're merge sorting, we can't easily help much more.  However, supposing that you're sorting an array of `int`, then the comparator might be:

```
int comparator(void const *v1, void const *v2)
{
    int i1 = *(int *)v1;
    int i2 = *(int *)v2;
    if (i1 < i2)
        return -1;
    else if (i1 > i2)
        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Note that this formulation avoids arithmetic overflow and other such undefined behaviour.  It is also a decent template for comparing structures and other more complex values; you can add more of the pairs of `<` and `>` tests until you've no more criteria for separating two values.

We can also observe that there's definitively a memory leak in your code.  You allocate an array inside the function, but you do not release it or return a pointer to it.

---

#### SSCCE with original `msort()` and `comparator()`

An SSCCE is a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int comparator(void const *v1, void const *v2)
{
    int i1 = *(int *)v1;
    int i2 = *(int *)v2;
    if (i1 < i2)
        return -1;
    else if (i1 > i2)
        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
}

static void sort_check(int *array, size_t n)
{
    size_t fail = 0;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (array[i-1] > array[i])
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Elements %zu (value %d) and %zu (value %d) are out of order\n",
                    i-1, array[i-1], i, array[i]);
            fail++;
        }
    }
    if (fail != 0)
        exit(1);
}

static void msort(void *b, size_t n, size_t s, int(*cmp)(const void*, const void*) )
{
    char *tmp;
    void *t;

    if ((t = malloc(s*n)) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: No Memory.\n");
        return;
    }

    char *b1, *b2;
    size_t n1, n2;

    n1 = n / 2;
    n2 = n - n1;
    b1 = b;
    b2 = (char *) b + (n1 * s);

    if (n2 <= n1)
        return;

    msort (b1, n2, s, cmp);
    msort (b2, n1+1, s, cmp);

    tmp = t;

    while (n1 > 0 && n2 > 0)
    {
        if ((*cmp) (b1, b2) <= 0)
        {
            memcpy (tmp, b1, s);
            tmp += s;
            b1 += s;
            --n1;
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy (tmp, b2, s);
            tmp += s;
            b2 += s;
            --n2;
        }
    }
    if (n1 > 0)
        memcpy (tmp, b1, n1 * s);
    memcpy (b, t, (n - n2) * s);
}

static int *gen_int_array(size_t n, int max_val)
{
    int *a = malloc(n * sizeof(*a));
    if (a == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = rand() % max_val;
    return(a);
}

static int *clone_int_array(int *master, size_t n)
{
    int *a = malloc(n * sizeof(*a));
    if (a == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = master[i];
    return(a);
}

static void dump_array(FILE *fp, char const *tag, int *a, size_t n)
{
    char const *pad = "";
    fprintf(fp, "Array: %s (size %zu)\n", tag, n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s%d", pad, a[i]);
        pad = ",";
    }
    putc('\n', fp);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n;
    int *a, *b;

    if (argc == 1)
        n = 10;
    else
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (n <= 0)
        n = 10;

    printf("running experiments with n = %d\n", n);

    a = gen_int_array(n, 5000);
    b = clone_int_array(a, n);

    dump_array(stdout, "Unsorted", a, n);

    printf("Q-Sort\n");
    qsort(a, n, sizeof(int), comparator);
    dump_array(stdout, "Q-sorted", a, n);
    sort_check(a, n);

    printf("M-Sort\n");
    msort(b, n, sizeof(int), comparator);
    dump_array(stdout, "M-sorted", b, n);
    sort_check(b, n);

    free(a);
    free(b);

    return(0);
}
```

The output for this (with no arguments, on Mac OS X 10.7.5) is:

```
running experiments with n = 10
Array: Unsorted (size 10)
1807,249,73,3658,3930,1272,2544,878,2923,2709
Q-Sort
Array: Q-sorted (size 10)
73,249,878,1272,1807,2544,2709,2923,3658,3930
M-Sort
Array: M-sorted (size 10)
1807,249,73,3658,3930,1272,2544,878,2923,2709
Elements 0 (value 1807) and 1 (value 249) are out of order
Elements 1 (value 249) and 2 (value 73) are out of order
Elements 4 (value 3930) and 5 (value 1272) are out of order
Elements 6 (value 2544) and 7 (value 878) are out of order
Elements 8 (value 2923) and 9 (value 2709) are out of order
```

As you can see, the `qsort()` gets the data in the correct order.  The `msort()` does not change the order of anything.  The test harness isn't set up to manage 0 rows of data, but running `msort 1` gets a core dump from the `msort()` function.  It's always a bad sign when a degenerate case fails with a segmentation fault.

The size 1 problem (and size 0) is fixed by checking `n` on entry to `msort()` and returning if `n <= 1`.

The next problem is the condition where `if (n2 <= n1)`; it returns early.  Indeed, that condition always fires for an even value of `n`; when you start with an odd value of `n`, the recursion generates an even value, and the early return kicks in.  Thus, the sorting never happens.  This is the (partially) instrumented version of the function that demonstrates this behaviour:

```
static void msort(void *b, size_t n, size_t s, int (*cmp)(const void *v1, const void *v2) )
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return;     /* Already sorted */

    printf("-->> msort(%zu)\n", n);
    void *t = malloc(s*n);

    if (t == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: No Memory.\n");
        printf("<<-- msort(%zu)\n", n);
        return;
    }

    size_t n1 = n / 2;
    size_t n2 = n - n1;

    if (n2 <= n1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops: %zu <= %zu\n", n2, n1);
        free(t);
        printf("<<-- msort(%zu)\n", n);
        return;
    }

    char *b1 = b;
    char *b2 = (char *) b + (n1 * s);

    msort(b1, n2, s, cmp);
    msort(b2, n1+1, s, cmp);

    char *tmp = t;

    while (n1 > 0 && n2 > 0)
    {
        if ((*cmp)(b1, b2) <= 0)
        {
            memcpy(tmp, b1, s);
            tmp += s;
            b1 += s;
            --n1;
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy(tmp, b2, s);
            tmp += s;
            b2 += s;
            --n2;
        }
    }
    if (n1 > 0)
        memcpy(tmp, b1, n1 * s);
    memcpy(b, t, (n - n2) * s);
    free(t);
    printf("<<-- msort(%zu)\n", n);
}
```

And sample runs:

```
running experiments with n = 1
Array: Unsorted (size 1)
1807
Q-Sort
Array: Q-sorted (size 1)
1807
M-Sort
Array: M-sorted (size 1)
1807

running experiments with n = 2
Array: Unsorted (size 2)
1807,249
Q-Sort
Array: Q-sorted (size 2)
249,1807
M-Sort
-->> msort(2)
Oops: 1 <= 1
<<-- msort(2)
Array: M-sorted (size 2)
1807,249
Elements 0 (value 1807) and 1 (value 249) are out of order

running experiments with n = 3
Array: Unsorted (size 3)
1807,249,73
Q-Sort
Array: Q-sorted (size 3)
73,249,1807
M-Sort
-->> msort(3)
-->> msort(2)
Oops: 1 <= 1
<<-- msort(2)
-->> msort(2)
Oops: 1 <= 1
<<-- msort(2)
<<-- msort(3)
Array: M-sorted (size 3)
249,73,1807
Elements 0 (value 249) and 1 (value 73) are out of order

running experiments with n = 4
Array: Unsorted (size 4)
1807,249,73,3658
Q-Sort
Array: Q-sorted (size 4)
73,249,1807,3658
M-Sort
-->> msort(4)
Oops: 2 <= 2
<<-- msort(4)
Array: M-sorted (size 4)
1807,249,73,3658
Elements 0 (value 1807) and 1 (value 249) are out of order
Elements 1 (value 249) and 2 (value 73) are out of order

running experiments with n = 5
Array: Unsorted (size 5)
1807,249,73,3658,3930
Q-Sort
Array: Q-sorted (size 5)
73,249,1807,3658,3930
M-Sort
-->> msort(5)
-->> msort(3)
-->> msort(2)
Oops: 1 <= 1
<<-- msort(2)
-->> msort(2)
Oops: 1 <= 1
<<-- msort(2)
<<-- msort(3)
-->> msort(3)
-->> msort(2)
Oops: 1 <= 1
<<-- msort(2)
-->> msort(2)
Oops: 1 <= 1
<<-- msort(2)
<<-- msort(3)
<<-- msort(5)
Array: M-sorted (size 5)
249,73,1807,3658,3930
Elements 0 (value 249) and 1 (value 73) are out of order

running experiments with n = 6
Array: Unsorted (size 6)
1807,249,73,3658,3930,1272
Q-Sort
Array: Q-sorted (size 6)
73,249,1272,1807,3658,3930
M-Sort
-->> msort(6)
Oops: 3 <= 3
<<-- msort(6)
Array: M-sorted (size 6)
1807,249,73,3658,3930,1272
Elements 0 (value 1807) and 1 (value 249) are out of order
Elements 1 (value 249) and 2 (value 73) are out of order
Elements 4 (value 3930) and 5 (value 1272) are out of order
```

It's your problem from here...I've shown some debug techniques, and diagnosed some of the problems.  Note that tracking function entry and exit can be helpful (though I cheated and didn't diagnose size 0 or 1 entry/exit).  Especially in recursive code, it helps a lot to identify the key parameter to the function (here, `n`, though the address of the start of the array might also be relevant) so that separate calls can be detected.

---

I got bored, or careless, or something...this code works.  Changes in the recursive calls, and the cleanup at the end of the merge loop, and the copy back to the original array.  And removed the dubious `if (n2 <= n1)` block altogether; I couldn't work out a purpose for it.  Oh, and more diagnostics, print array on entry and exit.

```
static void msort(void *b, size_t n, size_t s, int (*cmp)(const void *v1, const void *v2) )
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return;     /* Already sorted */

    printf("-->> msort(%zu)\n", n);
    dump_array(stdout, "Entry to msort()", (int *)b, n);
    void *t = malloc(s*n);

    if (t == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: No Memory.\n");
        printf("<<-- msort(%zu)\n", n);
        return;
    }

    size_t n1 = n / 2;
    size_t n2 = n - n1;

    char *b1 = b;
    char *b2 = (char *) b + (n1 * s);

    msort(b1, n1, s, cmp);
    msort(b2, n2, s, cmp);

    char *tmp = t;

    while (n1 > 0 && n2 > 0)
    {
        if ((*cmp)(b1, b2) <= 0)
        {
            memcpy(tmp, b1, s);
            tmp += s;
            b1 += s;
            --n1;
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy(tmp, b2, s);
            tmp += s;
            b2 += s;
            --n2;
        }
    }
    if (n1 > 0)
        memcpy(tmp, b1, n1 * s);
    else if (n2 > 0)
        memcpy(tmp, b2, n2 * s);
    memcpy(b, t, n * s);
    free(t);

    dump_array(stdout, "Exit from msort()", (int *)b, n);
    printf("<<-- msort(%zu)\n", n);
}
```